# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, typeerror

I am working on a terminal game. The game field is occupied with fieldCharacters (░) and holes (O)

The field is generated randomly but I also want to ensure that the pathCharacter (*) always lands in the top left of the field (which is made up of a set amount of arrays)

To do this I assigned the first index of the first array to pathCharacter (*). See code below:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

hat = '^';

hole = 'O';

fieldCharacter = '░';

pathCharacter = '*';

class Field {
  constructor(field) {
    this._field = field;
  }

  print() {
    this._field = field.join('\n');
    console.log(this._field.replace(/,/g, ''))
  }

  static generateField(height, width) {
    let finalArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      finalArray.push(fieldCharacter.repeat(width));
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
      let randomHoleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
      let randomHoleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
      finalArray[randomHoleY] = finalArray[randomHoleY].replaceAt(randomHoleX, hole);
    }

    // what I tried to do
    finalArray[0][0] = pathCharacter;
    return finalArray.join('\n').replace(/,/g, '');
  }
}

console.log(Field.generateField(5, 10));
```

What was outputted: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string '░░O░░░░░░O'

Example of what I want:

```
*░░O░░░░░O
░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░O░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░
░░░O░O░░░░
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things I'd fix.

- First, you really shouldn't add your own methods to `String.prototype`; that way lies madness if you want any sort of maintainability.
- Second, your `print()` method can't work (it's referring to an implicit global `field` to modify the instance field `_field`) – not that you're using it anyway, though.
- You should probably use an array of arrays instead of strings, for less awkward manipulation.
- You don't need a class for `Field`:

```
const hat = "^";
const hole = "O";
const fieldCharacter = "░";
const pathCharacter = "*";

function generateField(height, width) {
  const field = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    field.push(Array.from(fieldCharacter.repeat(width)));
  }
  for (let y = 0; y < field.length; y++) {
    const randomHoleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * height);
    const randomHoleX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
    field[randomHoleY][randomHoleX] = hole;
  }

  field[0][0] = pathCharacter;
  return field;
}

function printField(field) {
  for (let y = 0; y < field.length; y++) {
    console.log(field[y].join(""));
  }
}

const field = generateField(5, 10);
printField(field);
```

This outputs

```
*░░░░░░░░░
░░O░░░░░░░
░░░░O░░░░░
░░░░░░░░░░
O░O░░░O░░░
```