# pdfmake, TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string

Tags: angular, pdfmake

I'm trying to create a PDF using pdfMake with Angular.

I try to fill an Html table with data from an array. It's an array of object.

```js
export interface OrderDetails {
    orderId?   : number;
    truckMenuId: number;
    price?     : number;
    quantity   : number;
    truckMenu?  : TruckMenu;
    title?: string;
}
```

The method below ask an OrderDetails array as parameter.

```js
  public generatePDF(truck: Truck, orderItems: OrderDetails[]) { 
    let rows: string[] = ['Price', 'Quantity'];
    orderItems.forEach((item) => {
      var lign = [item.price, item.quantity];
      rows.push(<string><unknown>lign);
    })  
   
    let docDefinition = {
      content: [
       {  
            text: truck.name,  
            fontSize: 20,  
            alignment: 'center',  
            color: '#FF4F02',
            margin: [0, 20],
          },  
          {  
            text: 'Facture',  
            fontSize: 14,  
            bold: true,  
            alignment: 'Left',  
            decoration: 'underline',  
            color: '#000',
            margin: [0, 20]
         },
          {
          table: {
                   widths: ['*', 70, 50],
                   body: rows
                }
              },
               {
                   text: 'Total : ',
                   fontSize: 14,
                   alignment: 'right',
                   margin: [140,20]
               },
               {
                   text: 'Thanks',
                   fontSize: 12,
                   margin: [0,20]
               }
      ],
    }  
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();  
  }
```

As you can see, I use a forEach to loop into the array and display the data.

My problem is that a get an error message but I don't understand why.

`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'Price'`

I found the same error message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968781/typeerror-cannot-assign-to-read-only-property-0-of-string) but this doesn't solved my problem.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the solution.

I change rows type by any[] and push element like below:

```js
...
  
var rows: any[] = [];
rows.push(['Plats', 'Prix unitaire', 'Quantité']);

orderItems.forEach((item) => {
    rows.push([item.title, item.price, item.quantity]);
}) 
...
```